# How to call SQL native function, requiring constant argument, with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to get query that look like that:

```
select count(*) from somewhere group by DATEDIFF(week, '2010-01-01', creation_date);
```

My problem is on the function call. I'm using JPA's CriteriaBuilder (cb) with Hibernate underneath (root is my Somewhere):

```
cb.function("DATEDIFF", Integer.class, cb.literal("week"), cb.literal('2010-01-01'), root.<Date>get("creationDate")
```

Generated SQL is:

```
select count(*) from somewhere group by DATEDIFF(?, ?, creation_date);
- param1: 'week'
- param2: '2010-01-01'
```

which is not working because first function argument should be a constant not a "?".

How can I give this constant argument injected like it (no quotes, not as parameter)?

Thanks

My object in that case is something like:

```
@Entity
public class Somewhere {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationDate;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: can you try cb.parameter(String.class, "week") instead of cb.literal("week") and tell me what happen ?

Comment: Already tried, it just complain that parameter week hasn't be set. And when I set it, it become exactly what it was using literal ( question mark on the query, with a parameter set later).

Comment: Setting literals through the JPA criteria API isn't possible at the moment, the values will always be inserted as parameters. You could create your own `DATEDIFF` functions by implementing the `SQLFunction` interface and register e.g. day_diff, month_diff, etc. which have the first argument fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Christian comment, solution is actually quite simple to implement.

**Sql Server dialect** with new function 'weekdiff':

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class ExtendedSqlServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public ExtendedSqlServerDialect() {
        registerFunction("weekdiff", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "datediff(week, ?2, ?1)"));
    }
}
```

And then, just need ask Hibernate to use this dialect (I'm using spring boot).

**application.yml**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: com.xxx.dialect.ExtendedSqlServerDialect
```

And **code sample** where I'm using it:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb /* = ... */;
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Upload> root = query.from(Somewhere.class);
query.groupBy(cb.function("weekdiff",
    Integer.class,
    root.get("creationDate"),
    cb.parameter(String.class, "refDate")).alias("week")
);
```

And because I'm using HSQLDB on my unit test, here corresponding **HSQLDB dialect**:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class ExtendedHsqlDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

    public ExtendedHsqlDialect() {
        registerFunction("weekdiff", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "truncate(datediff('day', ?2, ?1) / 7)"));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't use this function on a Group By clause (see [Why ORDER BY DATEDIFF raise an exception on SQL server using JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657946/why-order-by-datediff-raise-an-exception-on-sql-server-using-jpa/42658409#42658409))