# Why ORDER BY DATEDIFF raise an exception on SQL server using JPA?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

This is working as expected:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select datediff(week, '2017-01-02', creation_date), count(*) from somewhere group by datediff(week, '2017-01-02', creation_date)",
        new RowMapper() {
            Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return [rs.getObject(1), rs.getObject(2)]
            }
        }
)
```

But I get this exception when I run query below:

```
SQLServerException: Column 'somewhere.creation_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

The query:

```
def date = new Date(117, 0, 2)
jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select datediff(week, ?, creation_date), count(*) from somewhere group by datediff(week, ?, creation_date)",
        new RowMapper() {
            Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return [rs.getObject(1), rs.getObject(2)]
            }
        },
        date,
        date
)
```

JPA Implementation is Hibernate 5.0.11.
I'm using Spring & Groovy for the demo but actual code is plain java + JPA Criteria, obviously with the same issue.

Why this is not working? I'm selecting only things that are in Group By clause. And the date is the same: it's even the same instance!

Comment: can you try >> GROUP BY creation_date HAVING datediff(week, ?, creation_date)

Answer (score 2):

Not being familiar with JPA, I can't say for certain, but I'm guessing those `?` get expanded into `@P1` and `@P2` by the time it makes it to SQL Server, so your `GROUP BY` would be different than your `SELECT`.

Your SQL Statement probably looks like this to SQL Server:

```
SELECT @P1 = '2017-01-02', @P2 = '2017-01-02';
select datediff(week, @P1, creation_date), count(*) 
from somewhere 
group by datediff(week, @P2, creation_date)
```

Comment: Interesting! That's mean the issue is actually coming (or could be fixed) in JPA implementation (Hibernate in my case). I'll try...

Answer (score 2):

Because the query uses parameter markers (`?`), the SQL Optimizer cannot know that both markers will have the same value, so the result expression is considered to be different from the grouping expression.

You need to calculate the expression in a nested statement, so grouping and result can use the *same* intermediate value:

```
def date = new Date(117, 0, 2)
jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select weekdiff, count(*)" +
         " from ( select datediff(week, ?, creation_date) as weekdiff" +
                  " from somewhere" +
              " ) x" +
        " group by weekdiff",
        new RowMapper() {
            Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return [rs.getObject(1), rs.getObject(2)]
            }
        },
        date
)
```

Comment: Well, same code is working for MySQL and HSQLDB. But I think you're right, that's the best solution for SQL Server. That's just not going to help my already complex and dynamically generated query...